# Installing FFMpeg in Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, ffmpeg, lumen

I am using Lumen (of Laravel) as my backend and using vagrant. I am want to install and use FFmpeg but I got confused how to install it.

Do I need to install it on my localhost or add it to Lumen? or both?

I found [this page](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide) but I got lost which commands to run.

---

Update: I installed [this repo](https://github.com/joshfng/install_ffmpeg) on Github and run it in vagrant. I think this installed the latest version on my local server, but what should I do next? How can I install and use FFMpeg with Lumen in php?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to your Homestead folder, run `vagrant ssh`. This will get you into your vagrant machine's terminal. Run command `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg` there and acknowledge the questions you get asked. (Additional libraries for PHP integration might be required.) FFMpeg will be ready to use.